# Is there a relation between principle of addition, principle of multiplication and mutually exclusive, independent events?

Tags: permutations, combinations

My understanding is as follows:

(a) If we have two events that are independent, then we can directly apply the principle of multiplication

(b) If we have two events that are mutually exclusive, then we can directly apply the principle of addition

But it's also possible that we can apply the principle of multiplication when events are mutually exclusive, but we just have to be more careful, and similarly we can apply the principle of addition when events are independent, but again we just have to be more careful. But, in this case why to do the extra work, so we can just use the respective counting methods here!

If those principle do have a relation, then what would happen in the case where the events are neither, necessarily, mutually exclusive or independent? like: Find the number of ways to "pick a fruit" and "pick an orange" from 3 apples and 4 orange, these events are neither, necessarily,  mutually exclusive or independent because it depends on the choice

I understand what "principle of multiplication" and "principle of addition" is, but i am getting confused as to: is there a relation between the rules and types of events on which the rules are being applied

Also, is it the case that mutually exclusive events are always denoted by "or" and independent events are always denoted by "and"?

Comment: Are these what you refer to with principle of multiplication and addition? 1. If A and B are independent, then $P(A$ and $B)=P(A)P(B)$ and 2. If A and B are mutually exclusive, then $P(A$ or $B)=P(A)+P(B)$?

Comment: @AntonV. This is more with regards to just "counting" and not probabilities. But yes, if A and B are independent then: number of ways to count them are m x n ways

Comment: It may be better to include a Single Example where all these are involved. It will enable getting better Answers. **My Suggestion** :: take a set of 8 Adults & 8 Children having 8 males & 8 females. Now make some Independent & Mutually Exclusive & Neither "Events" which you want to Count with Addition & Multiplication. Then list your Questions about which to use where & the Specific Confusion you have.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Consider the above diagram. Let this be a type of map connecting place A to C via B.
Here, each line represents a mode of travel and the number represents the number of routes that can be taken by that mode.

Now we know how to find the number of ways to go from A to C.
It's basically (2+3+2)(3+4)

Let's consider that we don't use the principle of counting. In that case, say we first go from A to B by the top mode. This yields 2 ways. Now for each route in this mode, we have (3+4) options. Thus, in total for this mode, we have (3+4) + (3+4) options which is basically $2(3+4)$ ways for this mode. By extension, we can say there will be a total of $7 \times 7$ ways to go from A to C via B. This is the same result which we get by the principle of counting.

Now let's analyse this. We can see that we can say the number of ways to go from A to B to C is basically:

(Mode 1 Route 1 [7 ways from B to C]) or (Mode 1 Route 2 [7 ways from B to C]) or (Mode 2 Route 1 [7 ways from B to C])... and so on.

Observe that this is basically the addition principle. This is the fundamental relation between the addition and multiplication rules. It stems from the basic fact that multiplication is repeated addition.

To answer your follow-up question, the word 'and' usually implies that the events occur in succession (both tasks must be done) and hence implies the usage of the multiplication rule. Similarly the word 'or' usually implies that the events are independent and we must choose which task we want to do and hence the addition rule is used.